# Trouble executing mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute this php code:

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$nm=$_GET['nm'];
$em=$_GET['em'];
$pa=$_GET['pa'];
$jb=$_GET['jb'];
$jbd=$_GET['jbd'];
$sk=$_GET['sk'];
$ds=$_GET['ds'];



$sql = " UPDATE fos_user SET  nom = ? , email = ? , pays = ? ,job = ?,  
addressjob = ?, skills = ? , description = ?  WHERE id='173';";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error: UPDATE fos_user SET nom = ? , email = ? , pays = ? ,job = ?, addressjob = ?, skills = ? , description = ? WHERE id='173';
>   Syntax error near '? , email = ? , pays = ? ,job = ?, addressjob = ?, skills = ? , description = ?' line 1

Comment: You need to [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [`bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) not execute the query. Secondly, use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to validate your data, it might not be present.

Comment: `mysqli` doesnt know what to bind. You need to explicitly define that. The `173` should also be bound. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.